# Is is possible to create a webpage with pagination but no database?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It's a shared hosting and I only have access to the FTP, so there is no database. I don't need the database to be honest. However I want to create a page that display some movie covers and I would like to sort by date and alphabetical order, and maybe have a pagination. Is it possible to put all the movies into a JSON file (create the JSON file manually) and fetch the data using JavaScript's Fetch API? I think that would act like a mini database. Am I right? As I said I don't need anything fancy just showing some movie covers and that's all.

Comment: Yes you can. put that JSON file into the public directory and then you can send a ajax request to fetch the json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always fetch all the data from an API/file and only render it partially.
This is called client side pagination, useful for lowering the load on browser and memory. Even pagination libraries has dedicated support for this mode, for example [backbone.paginator - client mode](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator#id2)

Comment: This method gives a very responsive user interface but the loading time increases linearly with the "number of movies" x "the amount of information per movies". Not efficient if user check just a few movies in huge list.

I advise you to store your data in some excel sheet and generate the json with script or a simple concatenate in the last column. Add the header in top cells of that column and then copy paste it in notepad to get your json. It's fast and safer and easier to edit than json. Also you'll get your Data ready for import in database if one day there are too many movies.

Comment: You can also build the list in Google spreadsheet (or similar) and read the json version of it from your website.